# Change Toostrip Order

Tags: c#, toolstrip

Im currently adding toolstrips from my seperate modules like:

```
this.toolStripContainer.TopToolStripPanel.Controls.Add(module.Instance.Toolbar)
```

Buy they are then in the order that the modules are loaded which isnt very good. Is there any way to re-order them?

Or should I be looking at adding some sort of index to my modules and laoding them in the order that I want the toolstrips?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up adding all the toolstrips to a list...
sorting the list by ToolStrip.Tag...
and then adding them to the control list...

This allows the module writer to set a priority for the toolstrip, kind of like toolstrip merging

Answer (score 3):

The Controls collection has a [SetChildIndex(Control child, int newIndex)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.setchildindex.aspx) method. See if you can use that method to order the controls as per your need.

**EDIT:** Just did a quick test. You need to call SuspendLayout() before adding the controls and then ResumeLayout() once you're done:

```
        this.toolStripContainer1.TopToolStripPanel.SuspendLayout();
        this.toolStripContainer1.TopToolStripPanel.Controls.Add(t1);
        this.toolStripContainer1.TopToolStripPanel.Controls.Add(t2);
        this.toolStripContainer1.TopToolStripPanel.Controls.SetChildIndex(t1, 1);
        this.toolStripContainer1.TopToolStripPanel.ResumeLayout();
```

Comment: SetChildIdex appears to have no effect, should i be re-freshing the control or something?

Comment: Maybe try putting a call to SuspendLayout() before adding and reordering, and then a ResumeLayout after you're done: this.toolStripContainer1.TopToolStripPanel.SuspendLayout();

Comment: it seems to work, but i have to cycle through the modules twice, once to add them, and then again to set the index.

Answer (score 0):

I solved like this:

```
StripContainer.TopToolStripPanel.Join(
    Instance.MMethod.Main.ToolStripMenu,
    StripContainer.TopToolStripPanel.Controls[
        StripContainer.TopToolStripPanel.Controls.Count - 1].Right, 
    0);
```